# VS2017 Android and SQLite

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-sqlite

Perhaps a dumb question but I can't find an answer anywhere!

I have a sqlite pre-populated database in my application which I need to copy to the device when the user install the application, I have the database in the Assets folder in VS2017 and have marked it as Embedded Resource but I can't seem to find the right path to access it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? am I on the right path here or is there some other magic that needs to happen somewhere?

Thanks
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a working directory in device external storage

```
public void createDirectory()
{
    bool isExists=false;
    string folderExternal;

    try
    {
        // folder path
        folderExternal = "/mnt/sdcard/Sample";

        // checking folder available or not
        isExists= System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderExternal);

        // if not create the folder
        if(!isExists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderExternal);

        folderExternal = "/mnt/sdcard/Sample/WorkingDB";
        isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderExternal);

        if(!isExists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderExternal);
    }
}
```

Then copy your db from asset folder

```
public void CopyDBFileFromAssetFolder()
{
    try{
        //checking file exist in location or no
        if (!File.Exists (Constants.DatabasebFilePath))
        {    
            //display progress bar or loader animation
            // Java thread is used for creating or copying
            // database file because this will not make the program non responsive

            new Java.Lang.Thread(() =>
            {
                // calling data from Asset folder
                using (var asset =  Assets.Open ("Empty_DB.db"))
                using (var dest = File.Create ( AppGlobal.DatabasebFilePath))
                {
                    // copying database from Asset folder to external storage device
                    asset.CopyTo (dest);
                }

                RunOnUiThread(() => onSuccessfulLogin());
            }).Start();
        }

    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fahadsk, it all makes sense except this line fails with "FileNotFoundException" when trying "using (var asset =  Assets.Open ("stocktake.db"))"

I have checked and I know the file is in the Assets directory in the project at least...

Comment: I guess you forgot to set `Build Action` as `AndroidAsset` 

`Right Click on file > Properties > Build Action > AndroidAsset`

Comment: Of course, yes, I missed that, thanks I am getting an Access Denied when trying to create the directory in /mnt/sdcard though. I'll try a different path.

Comment: I suspect you are missing permission to read and write to external storage in manifest put these permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: Thanks Fahadsk :)

Comment: AppGlobal.DatabasebFilePath Object give me Error ( can any one tell me that in Library this object belong because i am new to Android Develop Thanks in Advance)